# Ant design Form validation is not working and not updating input values when component is from a state that is passed from a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Can not validate the form item when sent from a function using state. Also the 'Select' values are not updating when changing options.

I am using components from Ant design. If I use 'select' instead of 'Select' then the value got updated but no solution on validation issue.

Tried async-await since there can be an issue of updating state. Didn't work.

Here is my code.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Form, Radio, Button, Select } from "antd";

const apiData = ["a", "b", "c"];

class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      viewState: []
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
      }
    });
  };

  view = e => {
    if (e.target.value === "p") {
      let options = apiData.map(element => {
        return (
          <Select.Option key={element} value={element}>
            {element}
          </Select.Option>
        );
      });
      this.setState({
        viewState: (
          <Form.Item>
            {this.props.form.getFieldDecorator("brunch", {
              rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please select your brunch!" }]
            })(<Select placeholder="select brunch">{options}</Select>)}
          </Form.Item>
        )
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
        <Form.Item>
          {this.props.form.getFieldDecorator("option", {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please select option!" }]
          })(
            <Radio.Group onChange={this.view}>
              <Radio value="p">p</Radio>
              <Radio value="q">q</Radio>
            </Radio.Group>
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        {this.state.viewState}
        <Form.Item>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            htmlType="submit"
            className="login-form-button"
          >
            Log in
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.create({ name: "normal_login" })(
  NormalLoginForm
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <WrappedNormalLoginForm />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check this code, it works fine. You missed the event handler call.

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Form, Radio, Button, Select } from "antd";

const apiData = ["a", "b", "c"];
const { Option } = Select;

class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      viewState: []
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(value) {
    this.setState({
      viewState: value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
      }
    });
  };

  view = e => {
    if (e.target.value === "p") {
      let options = apiData.map(element => {
        return (
          <Option key={element} value={element}>
            {element}
          </Option>
        );
      });
      this.setState({
        viewState: (
          <Form.Item>
            {this.props.form.getFieldDecorator("brunch", {
              rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please select your brunch!" }]
            })(
              <Select
                placeholder="select brunch"
                // onChange={(e = this.handleChange(e))}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              >
                {options}
              </Select>
            )}
          </Form.Item>
        )
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
        <Form.Item>
          {this.props.form.getFieldDecorator("option", {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please select option!" }]
          })(
            <Radio.Group onChange={this.view}>
              <Radio value="p">p</Radio>
              <Radio value="q">q</Radio>
            </Radio.Group>
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        {this.state.viewState}
        <Form.Item>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            htmlType="submit"
            className="login-form-button"
          >
            Log in
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.create({ name: "normal_login" })(
  NormalLoginForm
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <WrappedNormalLoginForm />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort but this is still not a solution. I need to show warning when none selected and need to show the value inside the select input box.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set initialValue as empty array

```
    {this.props.form.getFieldDecorator("option", {
                initialValue: [],
                rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please select option!" }],
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add 2 things - the form instance and the Form.Item name -

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Form, Radio, Button, Select } from "antd";

const apiData = ["a", "b", "c"];

class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     form: Form.useForm()
      viewState: []
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
      }
    });
  };

  view = e => {
    if (e.target.value === "p") {
      let options = apiData.map(element => {
        return (
          <Select.Option key={element} value={element}>
            {element}
          </Select.Option>
        );
      });
      this.setState({
        viewState: (
          <Form.Item name="brunch">
            {this.props.form.getFieldDecorator("brunch", {
              rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please select your brunch!" }]
            })(<Select placeholder="select brunch">{options}</Select>)}
          </Form.Item>
        )
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Form form={form} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
        <Form.Item name={"radioButtonFormItem"}>
          {this.props.form.getFieldDecorator("option", {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please select option!" }]
          })(
            <Radio.Group onChange={this.view}>
              <Radio value="p">p</Radio>
              <Radio value="q">q</Radio>
            </Radio.Group>
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        {this.state.viewState}
          <Button
            type="primary"
            htmlType="submit"
            className="login-form-button"
          >
            Log in
          </Button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to update state of forms on change. You can update as below from a function.

```js
setFieldsValue = obj => {
    this.props.form.setFieldsValue({ [obj.name]: obj.value });
  };
```

obj.name is the name of your field decorator in your case 'option'.